# What's the easieat way to get the latest uploaded file in S3 (when other existing files get overwritten) - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp

I have a S3 bucket and some Python code, the code read all the available files for the current day and download them to s3 (**it reads the files from FTP in an ascending order, based on the datetime in the filename when the file gets uploaded to FTP**), so for example I have downloaded `file 1` and `file 2` in the last run and uploaded them to S3, now I know FTP has a new file `file 3` available, then a new run will download files in the following order: `file1` `file2` and `file3` and upload all the files again in the same order to the same S3 path (`file1` and `file2` gets overwritten, and new file `file 3` will also be uploaded to s3).

My question is what's the easiest way to identify the newly-uploaded file `file3` in Python?

Comment: What's your current code that attempts to do it and why it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of to see the difference between 'updated' files and newly created files is simply doing a try/except GetObject before the PutObject. This is preferred over first doing the PutObject then trying to figure out what changed since S3 has no easy way of retrieing objects by 'Modified date' or simular.

So if your question was about checking which files were already present in S3 before uploading, try doing the GetObject first :).

Comment: Thanks, do you mean checking the existing files with `GetObject` first, then upload files, then use `GetObject` again, and compare the difference to identify the newly-created files?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. If you just want to see if a file with the same name was already present in S3, a succesful GetObject  means the file was there and you have indeed overwritten the file. If the GetObject returns a "object not found" error you know you are creating a new file. Whether or not the contents changed is a bit more tricky but there are of course ways to do this.